# Why I got a strange result for fdisk -l

Tags: disk

```
root@host [~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdc: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2444c1ab

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1       15566   125033863+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 300.1 GB, 300069052416 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36481 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00063841

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       36481   293033601   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004af28

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1       31130   250051693+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdd: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc33adbf6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1          14      103424   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdd2              14         536     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdd3             536       15567   120735744   83  Linux

Disk /dev/md127: 128.0 GB, 128033553408 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 31258191 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x27dd27dc
```

what is /dev/md127?

I usually have /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc. What is /dev/md127?

Also why /dev/sdc is listed first?

Answer (score 0):

`fdisk -l` lists all the partitions of all disks. If you want to print the partitions of a particular disk, for example /dev/sda try to do `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

`/dev/md` stands for RAID setups

Comment: shy sda is not the first?